# Scipy.optimize Inequality Constraint - Which side of the inequality is considered?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am using the scipy.optimize module to find optimal input weights that would minimize my output. From the examples I've seen, we define the constraint with a one-sided equation; then we create a variable that's of the type 'inequality'. My question is how does the optimization package know whether the sum of the variables in my constraint need to be smaller than 1 or larger than 1?

...

```
def constraint1(x):
    return x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]-1
```

....

```
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
```

link to full solution I'm using in my example:
http://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonOptimization

Comment: [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) says "Equality constraint means that the constraint function result is to be zero whereas **inequality means that it is to be non-negative**."

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Refer to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/optimize.html and scroll down to Constrained minimization of multivariate scalar functions (minimize), you can find that

> This algorithm allows to deal with constrained minimization problems
> of the form:

[image]

where the inequalities are of the form `C_j(x) >= 0`.

So when you define the constraint as

```
def constraint1(x):
    return x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]-1
```

and specify the type of the constraint as

```
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
```

it automatically assumes that the constraint is in the standard form `x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]-1>=0` i.e., `x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]>=1`

Comment: Just as a remark, I was searching for `x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]<10` and this works through simple bringing 10 to the left then multiply it all with -1.  In any case, try to get the the standard form and then adjust as necessary.