# Optimize non-scalar function with inequality constraint and bounds

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, least-squares, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am looking for an optimization method in scipy which allows me to minimize object function f(x,y) (returns vector) subject to the constraint g(x,y) < 0.1 and additional bounds on x and y.

I have tried to solve my problem with scipy.optimize.least_squares, scipy.optimize.leastsq and scipy.optimize.minimize. The problem is that leastsq and least_squares allow the object function to be non-scalar, but does not give me the possibility of implementing a constraint (only bounds). minimize on the other hand gives me the possibility of implementing both a constraint and bounds, but f(x,y) must return a scalar. Hence, I am looking for a solution that combines both. Does anyone know whether something like this exists?

The function I want to minimize is

```py
def my_cost(p,f_noise):
    x,y = p[0], p[1]
    f = #some function that returns a 3x1 array
    return (f - fnoise)**2
```

I did this with the least_squares method.

```py
opti.least_squares(my_cost, p0[:], args = (f_noise,),gtol=1e-2, bounds=bounds)
```

But here I have the problem that I cannot constrain the variables in p. I need to constrain p so that it fulfils

```py
def constraint(p)
    x = p[0]
    return fy(x) - y <= 0.1 #variable y therefore becomes a function of variable x
```

To implement the constraint, I tested scipy's minimize function

```py
opti.minimize(my_cost, p0[:], args = (f_noise,), bounds = bounds, constraints={'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint})
```

But here I can't seem to find a way to allow my_cost and f_noise to be 3x1 arrays.

For any help I am very grateful!
Cheers for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), the objective function must return a float when using `scipy.optimize.minimize`, whereas with `scipy.optimize.least_squares`, you cannot use constraints.
In this case, you have to be aware of your minimization purpose. Minimizing a difference vector (like `f-f_noise`) is equivalent to minimizing the element-wise differences and consequently their sum. Therefore a practical solution would be to minimize a defined p-norm of your `f(x,y)` and `g(x)`. I suggest the square ***L2-norm*** as it is very similar to what you are trying in your cost function and it is simple and stable (in comparison to other norms).

[image]

You can average the norm and get the [Mean Squared Error (MSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error):

[image]

By applying the previous concepts, you get the following code:

```py
import numpy as np 
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# define fy
def fy(x):
    return x**2 * np.array([[.1],[.2],[.3]])  # some function that returns a 3x1 array

# objective func
def f(p, f_noise):
    x, y = p[0], p[1]
    f    = x * y * np.array([[1],[2],[3]])    # some function that returns a 3x1 array
    return np.linalg.norm(f - f_noise, 2)**2

# constraint
def g(p):
    x         = p[0]
    diff_norm = np.linalg.norm(fy(x) - y) 
    return threshold - diff_norm 

# init 
f_noise   = np.array([[.1],[.2],[.3]])
p0        = np.array([1, 0.5])
bounds    = ((0,2),(0,2))
y         = np.array([[.9],[.7],[.2]])
threshold = 0.1  # make sure to choose an adequate threshold

# minimize
result  =  minimize(f, p0,
                    args        = (f_noise,), 
                    bounds      = bounds, 
                    constraints = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': g})

# print result
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful and quick answer, SuperKogito! That's amazing! I will test it and reply later, wether this solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, SuperKogito. This seems to work allthough I am still running some tests. I have one question to this solution: The constraint is select via the threshold. Doesn't this reduce the found solution to the best value where threshold = diff_norm instead of best value for diffnorm < threshold? I.e. in your solution I understand the constraint to be g(x,y) = 0.1 instead of g(x,y) < 0.1. Seems to be some kind of Lagrangian Constraint to me.

Comment: This depends more on the nature of your problem.  It is for you to decide which constraint type (equality or inequality) is more efficient in your case. I think an inequality is probably faster because trivially it is easier to find a value lower than the threshold compared to finding one that is equal to the threshold.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think it would be faster. I would like to constrain the the minimization to all points where g(x,y) < 0.1. But as I understand it, the code currently looks for a solution where g(x,y) is closest to 0.1. But I don't know how to implement the inequality constraint.

Comment: In my example, I am using the inequality constraint. I defined it in this line `constraints = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': g}`. Therefore, the minimization is looking for a solution while making sure that the return of the constraint is positive: `g(p) >= 0 -> threshold - diff_norm >= 0 -> threshold >= diff_norm`. Please read the constraint section [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) and refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303470/scipy-optimize-inequality-constraint-which-side-of-the-inequality-is-considere)

Comment: Ah perfect. I was looking for the 'ineq' command but must have overseen it. Thank you ever so much, Kogito! You helped me a lot!

Comment: You are welcome :) consider accepting the answer if it helped.