# Optimizing a function using Scipy Package

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization, scipy-optimize

I am given an objective function that I need to maximize using a **nonlinear** optimizer in Python. I understand that many optimizers are written as minimizations but I am having trouble setting up the parameters given that I have a few *inequality* constraints to be met. I checked the roots of my objective function using Wolfram Alpha optimizer and have x = 1.86121 and y = 1.07457.

I am also planning to check these roots and find the Lagrangian multipliers using the Lagrangian approach. Does anyone know how to setup this optimization problem using `Scipy.optimize`. I believe I have to set up the constraints as separate functions but I do not know how. Thank you.

*Objective function:* **maximize 5-x^2-xy-3y^2**

*Subject to constraints:* **x>=0, y>=0, and xy >=2**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

def obj(x):
    return -1 * (5 - x[0]**2 - x[0]*x[1] - 3*x[1]**2)

def cons(x):
    return x[0]*x[1] - 2

result = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun = obj, x0 = [1, 1], bounds=[(0, np.inf), (0, np.inf)], constraints={"fun": cons, "type": "ineq"})
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303470/scipy-optimize-inequality-constraint-which-side-of-the-inequality-is-considere).

Comment: I see your logic but the output is wrong. Why didn't you add the constraints the ```x[0] and x[1] >= 0``` ?

Comment: Those constraints are in the `bound` parameter. The objective function has a typo: it should be `- (5 - x[0]**2 - x[0]*x[1] - 3*x[1]**2)`

Comment: Thanks @FBruzzesi. I fixed the typo and now it works.

Comment: @enesdemirag Thank you so much, it worked! You're both too kind

Comment: @enesdemirag Hello. I did this optimization like you showed and I get why you did what you did. But doing the math on paper I see that the result is a negative number for this optimization. Conceptually speaking if we minimize a function and it is a positive number is this the same as the maximization being a negative number? I know math I promise but the introduction of optimizers kinda confuses me

Comment: Minimizing f(x) and taking result as negative is different than minimizing -f(x). @eruiz