# python scipy.optimize.minimize "SLSQP solver" adding constraint between xo

Tags: python

I would like to optimize function with SLSQP solver. The function contains 5 parameters, and I would like to add a constraint that `x[0] > x[3]`. The following code makes `x[0]=x[3]`. Can you help me to modify it to "`x[0] > x[3]`"

```
cons = {'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0] - x[3]} 

res = minimize(model_calib, xo, bounds=[(100,8000),(0,650),(0,1),(5,550),(0,3)], method='SLSQP',constraints = cons)
```

Best regards,

Comment: You should use `'type': 'ineq'` for inequality type of constraints

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303470/scipy-optimize-inequality-constraint-which-side-of-the-inequality-is-considere

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in comment by @Cory Kramer

```
cons = {'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0] - x[3]}
```

Comment: Technically speaking, that is `>= 0` not just `> 0` as the OP requested

Comment: May be 'lambda x: x[0] - x[3]*(1 +  1e-15)' helps here.

Comment: Thanks for your support @balezz

May this solution give answer with x[3] > x[0]????

Comment: I have not  `model_calib` function, so can`t check this solution. Try it yourself and write what happens.